# Rotate image Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, rotation, raphael

I have the following jQuery:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 20, 500, 500);

var robot = paper.image("http://jackdent.co.uk/arrow-right.jpg", 0, 0, 20, 20);
robot.node.setAttribute('id', 'robot');

$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    $('#robot').rotate(90);
})
```

​I need for certain reasons to access the robot element using an id assigned to it. I want to rotate the image 90 degrees when the client clicks a button. Currently my code is erroneous, and I can't figure out why.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vre9W/17/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
robot.rotate(90);
```

instead of

```
$('#robot').rotate(90);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vre9W/18/

Comment: Thanks - thats perfect. How can I find out the rotation of the image and assign it to a variable?

Comment: @jacktheripper The reason this works is because `$("#robot")` is a jQuery object and `robot` is a Raphael object. You could save the Raphael object as jQuery data for the element so you can maintain the reference easily. `$("#robot").data('raphael-obj', robot)`, then in your `click` event handler you can do this: `$("#robot").data('raphael-obj').rotate(90);`